# panda.DataFrame error for analyzing stock data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was coding a Stock Analyzer program following this guide: https://towardsdatascience.com/in-12-minutes-stocks-analysis-with-pandas-and-scikit-learn-a8d8a7b50ee7

I got stuck on the part of the code which said

```
dfreg = df.loc[:,['Adj Close','Volume']]
dfreg['HL_PCT'] = (df['High'] - df['Low']) / df['Close'] * 100.0
dfreg['PCT_change'] = (df['Close'] - df['Open']) / df['Open'] * 100.0
```

First, it gave this error:

```
NameError: name 'df' is not defined
```

I changed it to pandas.DataFrame and it gave me this error:

```
TypeError: 'property' object is not subscriptable
```

I don't know how to fix this. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you do?:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import pandas_datareader.data as web
from pandas import Series, DataFrame


start = datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 11)

df = web.DataReader("AAPL", 'yahoo', start, end)
df.tail()
```

If df.tail() don`t show you the dataframe clean your workspace and try again because it show like you haven't load corectly the dataFrame --> df

Comment: Thanks. This made me realize my problem: I was reading data of multiple companies ad then didn't put df.trail()